# How to get unique data of WiFi Network in kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am creating an android app which can only load if connected to a specific wireless network. Getting the ssd from wifi manager returns  network. Is there a way I can achieve this in kotlin?

Tried getting ssd using WiFi manager but returns unknown network.

Comment: Do you have Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE and Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and any associated runtime permissions requested?  Without them, you can't access the SSID

Comment: Yes i have added needed permissions but still not returing the values i want

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

Comment: And here is the function am using to retrieve the data:

Comment: fun getUniqueConnectedWifiId(): String? {
        val wifiManager = getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
        val wifiInfo = wifiManager.connectionInfo
        val ssid = wifiInfo.ssid
        val mac=wifiInfo.macAddress
        val bssid = wifiInfo.bssid
        val networkid=ssid+mac+bssid
        return if (ssid != null && bssid != null) {
           // "$ssid:$bssid"
            networkid
        } else {
            null
        }
    }